# Spring how to get beans in a factory

Tags: java, spring

I have the following code :

```
public interface CreatorFactory<E extends Vehicle> {

    public VehicleType<E> getVehicle();

    public boolean supports(String game);
}

public abstract AbstractVehicleFactory<E extends Vehicle>  implements CreatorFactory {

        public VehicleType<E> getVehicle() {

           // do some generic init        

          getVehicle();

        }

        public abstract getVehicle();

        public abstract boolean supports(String game);

}
```

and i have multiple factories, for car, truck..etc..

```
@Component
public CarFactory extends AbstractVehicleFactory<Car> {

   /// implemented methods

}

@Component
public TruckFactory extends AbstractVehicleFactory<Truck> {

   /// implemented methods

}
```

What I would like to do is pull the implemented factories into a seperate class as a list, but im not sure how generics works in this case... I know in spring you can get all beans of a specific type... would this still work?...

With erasure, i guess the generic types would be removed .. ??

Comment: Which is the return type of  public abstract getVehicle();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I think there is maybe no need to get a list of beans. And you just want get the exact bean which has declared with generics type.

In BeanFactory interface in Spring framework, there is a method to use for your requirement:

```
public interface BeanFactory {

    /**
     * Return the bean instance that uniquely matches the given object type, if any.
     * @param requiredType type the bean must match; can be an interface or superclass.
     * {@code null} is disallowed.
     * <p>This method goes into {@link ListableBeanFactory} by-type lookup territory
     * but may also be translated into a conventional by-name lookup based on the name
     * of the given type. For more extensive retrieval operations across sets of beans,
     * use {@link ListableBeanFactory} and/or {@link BeanFactoryUtils}.
     * @return an instance of the single bean matching the required type
     * @throws NoSuchBeanDefinitionException if there is not exactly one matching bean found
     * @since 3.0
     * @see ListableBeanFactory
     */
    <T> T getBean(Class<T> requiredType) throws BeansException;
}
```

You can use code like:

```
Car carFactory = applicationContext.getBean( CarFactory.class );
Trunk trunkFactory = applicationContext.getBean( TrunkFactory.class );
```

or just see @Qualifier annotation for injection automaticly.

```
@Component("carFactory")
public CarFactory extends AbstractVehicleFactory<Car> {

   /// implemented methods

}

@Component("truckFactory ")
public TruckFactory extends AbstractVehicleFactory<Truck> {

   /// implemented methods

}
```

In client side code:

```
@Qualifier("carFactory")
@Autowired
private CarFactory carFactory ;

@Qualifier("truckFactory")
@Autowired
private TruckFactory TruckFactory;
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need:

```
@Autowired
List<AbstractVehicleFactory> abstractVehicleFactories;
```